# Problem with InnoDB "per table" file sizes

Tags: mysql, innodb

I Have configured the mysql server with `innodb per table`. There was a table `watchdog` having approximate 19GB of `watchdog.ibd` file.

I have truncated the table now it has zero record. But the `watchdog.ibd` have same size.

What's the issue.? Does `truncate` does not work for removing the data from the .ibd file..?

I don't want to drop the table because in need that table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please keep in mind that `TRUNCATE TABLE` is a DDL command that tells the InnoDB storage engine to pretend there are no records.

According to the MySQL Documentation on [TRUNCATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/truncate-table.html) :

> When fast truncation is used, it resets any AUTO_INCREMENT counter to
>   zero. From MySQL 5.0.13 on, the AUTO_INCREMENT counter is reset to
>   zero by TRUNCATE TABLE, regardless of whether there is a foreign key
>   constraint.)

However, doing `TRUNCATE TABLE` does nothing for space already allocated.

To quickly drop the space down to zero rows, you can do the following:

```
#
# Algorithm 1
#
CREATE TABLE watchdog_new LIKE watchdog;
ALTER TABLE watchdog RENAME watchdog_zap;
ALTER TABLE watchdog_new RENAME watchdog;
DROP TABLE watchdog_zap;
```

Since `TRUNCATE TABLE` tells mysql that the table is considered empty, you can do this:

```
#
# Algorithm 2
#
TRUNCATE TABLE watchdog;
ALTER TABLE watchdog ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

These two steps behave the same way as `Algorithm 1`.

These steps also can be done with

```
#
# Algorithm 3
#
TRUNCATE TABLE watchdog;
OPTIMIZE TABLE watchdog;
```

Internally, [OPTIMIZE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-table.html) would perform `Algorithm 1` and then perform [ANALYZE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/analyze-table.html). For InnoDB, the `ANALYZE TABLE` phase of `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is bypassed. In fact, it is unnecessary because [*index statistics are recomputed on each query executed against an InnoDB table*](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/12/09/thinking-about-running-optimize-on-your-innodb-table-stop/).

Comment: a correction, index statistics are not updated after every query.  They are updated after every 2 billion row operations, when 1/16th of the rows change, plus on certain metadata operations (ANALYZE TABLE, SHOW INDEXES FROM, SHOW TABLE STATUS) and most DDL operations.  See http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/10/06/when-does-innodb-update-table-statistics-and-when-it-can-bite/ for more information .

Comment: My mistake. Index statistics for InnoDB are computed by approximation via dives into an index. This is quickly seen when running `SHOW INDEX FROM` command on an InnoDB table multiple times and watching the `Cardinality` column change with each successive run.

Comment: @AaronBrown your link is a good one since real statistics must be compiled under certain situations.

Comment: SHOW INDEX FROM is a metadata operation and actually causes the index statistics to recompute unless you have innodb_stats_on_meatadata=0.  It's a case where observation changes the behavior.  I recommend turning innodb_stats_on_metadata off in most cases.

Comment: For the first example, you can use _RENAME TABLE_ which will move tables atomically: `RENAME TABLE watchdog TO watchdog_zap, watchdog_new to watchdog`

Comment: I second @RomualdBrunet's atomic rename. I checked the docs and atomic rename with multiple tables has been a feature since v.3.23.23.

Answer (score 1):

Space isn't normally removed from the InnoDB files

To reclaim space, you have to [OPTIMIZE TABLE](http://You%20can%20use%20OPTIMIZE%20TABLE%20to%20reclaim%20the%20unused%20space%20and%20to%20defragment%20the%20data%20file.) which creates temporary tables/files and switches them. Or otherwise force this process via another operation using a temporary table/`DROP`+`CREATE`/`CREATE TABLE..LIKE` etc